# find N neighbors of certain type in graph DB

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, dijkstra

Let's say I've got directed graph with 100k nodes and 500k edges. From them 15k nodes are 'important'. I need to find 100 nearest 'important' nodes starting from one specific node.

I've implemented Dijkstra algorithm in C#, which finds distance from starting node to all other nodes. Then I sort 'important' nodes by distance and return 100 first. This takes about 1 second.

Now I need to do the same at server side (Linux) with possibly many concurrent queries and different starting nodes. I've tried node4j graph database, and after consulting with the developers, we've got solution which does the same in 10-20 sec (actually, if we compute paths without length limit, it takes about 10 min). It takes so long, because neo4j stores all shortest paths, and my C# implementation stores only distances. The only option to make it faster in neo4j is to write extension which isn't trivial.

So question is: is there any graph db (non-commercial) that can be installed at Linux server and is able to run such query fast? I've checked all graph dbs from wikipedia list, and didn't find anything suitable.

Another option is to implement same algorithm in Java and make a service (Tomcat?) that will store shared copy of the graph (how?) and will answer these queries. But I'd prefer something ready...

Comment: How do you define your important nodes? Do you have a list? Or other properties? Any chance to share your graph or a generated similar graph?

Comment: What version of neo4j did you use?

Comment: important nodes are in special neo4j index, so I can get their list fast

Comment: basically graph is genealogical forest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing a Neo4j Extension to do this isn't as bad as you think.

See here for an example:
http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/11/26/extending-neo4j/

And this one does "custom" pathfinding using the A* algorithm:
http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/11/27/pathfinding-with-neo4j-unmanaged-extensions/

Comment: BTW: A* won't be an optimization over dijkstra in a one-to-many case. It could lead to little faster running times when you're doing a bidirectional search (for every 15k points)

Answer (score 1):

This is intended as a compliment to the answer @MaxDeMarzi gave...

You mention that your C# implementation: **(1)** finds distance from starting node to ALL other nodes, **(2)** SORTS 'important' nodes by distance, **(3)** returns 100 first.

To improve efficiency could you do something like this instead?

```
top = 100
```

Then, every time Dijkstra finds the shortest path to a new node:

```
if (isImportant(node)) resultSet.add(node,distance)
if (resultSet.size() >= top) return resultSet
```

This would avoid finding paths to nodes you're not interested in

Comment: You're right, I could stop after finding N nearest nodes. Just for client-side version 1 sec was more than enough. But for the server-side version it will be nice optimization.